# flutter application not installing in device

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2156 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,434ms
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...           7.3s
after this nothing happening

I try all thing like restarting IDE, restarting device, flutter clean, flutter pub get.
also tryed flutter run  --verbose, flutter channel stable but nothing happened.
also tryed uninstalling old application but now that old applications are not installing.